# Problem, merging cell in a table document, google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have one  table in a document, with 5 rows and 5 columns.

I need to merge the cell 1, and the cell 2 in the row 0.

This is my code  about merge.. But, I have a problem. The cells 1  and 2 don't merge. I dont know Why. **How I can I merge the cells in a table in a document?**

```
var doc=DocumentApp.create('EXAMPLE');
var table=doc.getBody().getTables()[0];
var row=table.getRow(0);
var cell1= row.getCell(1);
var cell2= row.getCell(2);
cell2.merge;
```

> Following Added by: Cooper

[In this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#merge()):

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
// Append two paragraphs to the document.
var par1 = body.appendParagraph('Paragraph 1.');
var par2 = body.appendParagraph('Paragraph 2.');

// Merge the newly added paragraphs into a single paragraph.
par2.merge();
```

It works as the elements are being created.  But of course this example is for paragraphs and not tables.

I tried this:

```
function mergeCells() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var table=doc.getBody().getTables()[0];
  var row=table.getRow(0);
  var cell= row.getCell(1);
  cell.getNextSibling().merge();
}
```

> And this works.  It merges the two desired cells of a table that is already on a document.  But causes some sort of error which requires the document to be reloaded.  **Can anyone explain this behavior.**

Before running last script:

[image]

This is the error dialog:

[image]

After running  script and reloading document:

[image]

I think if you try this script you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Have you tried **calling** the merge method? Here you do not *call* it. Compare `doc.getBody` which is a function, and `doc.getBody()`, which *invokes* the `getBody` function of the object referred to as the `doc` variable, with 0 arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions

Comment: Try this: `function mergeCells() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var table=doc.getBody().getTables()[0];
  var row=table.getRow(0);
  var cell= row.getCell(1);
  cell.getNextSibling().merge();
}
`

Comment: How I can to merge cells, without lose  the table appearance?  This code merge  the content of cells, but next, the  information of cells  is one space to the left.